# What is a simple and memory efficient way strip whitespace from a large string in Python

Tags: python, strip

I have a large string, >100mb in size.
I want to remove leading and trailing white space.
What is a simple and memory efficient way to do this?

**Consider the following problem:**

A 1Gb file will be partitioned for parallel processing.
This file is divided into 10 equal parts, each 100 Mb long.
A large part of these files is white space, so the leading and trailing white space is to be removed from each 100 Mb part.

Is there a memory efficient and simple way to strip this white space from the head and tail of each part.

Comment: `string.strip()`  Is there another way?

Comment: string.strip(), as in new_s = s.strip() appears to be creating intermediate string copies. This is occurring in a multiple processes, causing a lot of memory consumption.

Comment: Strings are immutable.  You have to create a copy to get the string stripped.

Comment: Where is the string coming from? Maybe you could prevent the whitespace from being added to it in the first place.

Comment: @EdTate Put that in the question.

Comment: You are unlikely to come up with a method better than the C implementation of `str.strip`

Comment: Where do you get a 100MB string? Is it the contents of a file?

Comment: The process starts with a 1Gb file, this is broken into 10 100Mb strings. The white space at the start and stop of the strings needs to be stripped. The naïve solution was to use s.strip(). However, memory usage is unacceptable. I'm looking for a simple and memory efficient way to accomplish strip without the copying.

Comment: Can't you do a check like `startswith(' ')` and `endswith(' ')`, and depending on the outcome of these statements, use `string[1:-1]` instead of string? The checks don't need much memory, and this way you don't use anything other then the existing string.

Comment: It sounds like there might be _a lot_ more than a single whitespace char in the start and the end, @Nander, so I doubt your suggestion would suffice.

Comment: Additionally, the source files may be from Linux or Windows. The white space includes tabs, newlines, spaces, returns, etc.

Comment: Do you mean there are many newlines in the string, with whitespace before them? You could strip it as you read it in and keep a list of lines instead.

Comment: Why does it all need to be in memory at the same time?

Comment: Do you know how long the non-whitespace parts of the files are? Because if yes, you could split the string further and do multiprocessing on those strings. If you only pass views to processes, no need to copy...

Comment: My guess is that Python is not the best language/tool to be used in your case. For information, the source code for the `strip()` method can be found here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#L1854 (2.7) and https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12038 (3.5)

Answer (score 0):

So, what is the memory on your target system? Unless you have less than 220MB RAM or so for the whole process, I think `str.strip` is what you should use there.

One could interactively consume the 1GB file to create a stripped 100MB part - but that would be cost intensive  - having to hold up to the full 100MB in an intermediate buffer (which could be allocated in a file, though) Bu that would be far from "simple" as you request - specially when compared with "strip()".

It could however be a nice way to strip whitespace from within the 100MB partitions if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Made this a long time ago. The functions return the stripped string, but you can rework them to return only the start and end indices and you work with them on the original string with no memory overhead.

```
inp = "00000a00f00000000t00h000000"

def strip_start(inp, char):
    inlen = len(inp)
    start=0
    found=0
    for t in xrange(0, inlen):
        if inp[t] != char:
            start = t
            found=1
            break

    return start, found

def strip_end(inp, char):
    inlen = len(inp)
    end=0
    found=0
    for t in xrange(inlen-1, -1, -1):
        if inp[t] != char:
            end = t+1
            found=1
            break

    return end, found

def strip_simple(inp, char):
    return inp[strip_start(inp, char)[0]:strip_end(inp, char)[0]]

def strip_by_blocks(inp, char, siz): #possibly better performance for large "siz" and "inp"
    inlen = len(inp)
    block = char*siz
    start=0
    for t in xrange(0, inlen, siz):
        if inp[t:t+siz] != block:
            start = strip_start(inp[t:t+siz], char)
            if start[1] == 1:
                start = t+start[0]
            else:
                start = 0
            break
    end=0
    if inlen>=siz:
        for t in xrange(inlen-siz, -siz, -siz):
            if inp[t:t+siz] != block:
                end = strip_end(inp[t:t+siz], char)
                if end[1] == 1:
                    end = t+end[0]
                else:
                    end = 0
                break
    else:
        end = strip_end(inp, char)[0]

    return inp[start:end]

print strip_simple(inp, "0")
print strip_by_blocks(inp, "0", 4)
```